# Returning a fetch inside a .get() request

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fetch

I cannot get this fetch request to work inside the .get() request. It works on its own, the console.log that says 'first player' returns the data i want, however, when I call this function inside the router.get() I get undefined (the console.log that says 'in the get' returns undefined).

```
const fetchPlayers = () => {
    const url = "https://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/draft-rankings/json/test"
    let res = fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data.DraftRankings[0], 'first player')
          return data.DraftRankings[0]
        })
}

router.get('/', async (req, res)=> {
    try {
        const players = await fetchPlayers();
        console.log(players, 'in the get');
        res.json(players)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err})
    }
})
```

I just want to be able to make the fetch request and be able to use that data in the router.get().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only `await` something that returns a promise.  You can solve this by forcing your function to return a promise by making it an async function.

```
const fetchPlayers = async () => {
    const url = "https://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/draft-rankings/json/test"
    const response = await fetch(url)
    return response.json()
}

router.get('/', async (req, res)=> {
    try {
        const players = await fetchPlayers();
        console.log(players, 'in the get');
        res.json(players)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err})
    }
})
```

Also, you're gonna want to use a try catch statement to handle errors in your fetch request.  Although if you cannot call json on the response object it will reject the promise anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```js
let res = fetch(url)...
```

At that point `res` holds a `Promise`.

The fix is to return from the called function:

```js
async function fetchPlayers() {
    const url = "https://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/draft-rankings/json/test"
    let res = await fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data.DraftRankings[0], 'first player')
          return data.DraftRankings[0]
        })

    return res;
}
```

You can make this more readable by using `await` syntax throughout:

```js
async function fetchPlayers() {
    const url = "https://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/draft-rankings/json/test"
    const request = await fetch(url);
    const data = await request.json();

    console.log(data.DraftRankings[0], 'first player');
    return data.DraftRankings[0];
}
```

As a general rule if you have a mix of `await` and `.then()` you can convert every `x(...).then(y => ...` into `const y = await x(...);`

Comment: Thanks, still learning about async/await and I'm using this as a way of practicing it. That last bit is very good to know